# Высота <span> по высоте содержимого

Tags: html, css

Как установить высоту `<span>` по высоте содержимого? Много пишут о том, как его растянуть по высоте родителя, но мало о том, как по содержимому.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моём примере (ссылка на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t75thkqb/)) `span` находится внутри `flex`, но тоже самое было и внутри `table-cell`.

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию, потомки родителя, у которого установлен `display: flex;` растягиваются по его высоте. Если есть необходимость сделать иначе, необходимо установить родителю свойство `align-items: flex-start / center;`.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  align-items: center;
}

.title {
  background-color: red;
}

.shortcut_hint {
  font-family: Consolas, sans-serif;
  font-size: 50%;
  background-color: #003366;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="title">Title</span>
  <span class="shortcut_hint">Ctrl+1</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! А как следует быть, если span внутри, например, table-cell, и зафлоачен вправо? Он тоже также растянется по высоте, но здесь причина будет уже другая.

Comment: Можете представить код? Пока что не очень понял что имеется в виду.

Comment: Попробовал переписать свой код в упрощённом варианте - всё [получилось](https://jsfiddle.net/t75thkqb/2/). Придётся ещё много времени искать причину в проекте.